# Strange requests which ends with -moz-zoom-in

Tags: html, css, firefox

Production server gets a lot (hundreds) of requests which ends with **-moz-zoom-in**.
It just adds **-moz-zoom-in** to current url, e.g. http://www.wikipaintings.org/en/paintings-by-genre/allegorical-painting/-moz-zoom-in

I made a search through project and did not find any mentions of this keyword. As I understand  from documentation this is related to firefox cursor type.

I wasn't able to see such requests with firebug.

Any ideas what in CSS or HTML could cause such effect?

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-zoom-in

Comment: I am wondering if it would also be called with `CTRL +` or custom font size settings

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the user agent string of the requests. I suspect that it is some browser that doesn't support `-moz-zoom-in` (meaning: not Firefox, so it is not surprising that you cannot see that request in Firebug). You probably have `cursor: -moz-zoom-in` somewhere in your CSS styles, probably through some third-party library like jQuery UI, and that browser "fixes" it for you and turns it into `cursor: url("-moz-zoom-in")`. So it actually tries to load the cursor from that URL instead of ignoring the invalid cursor.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, it is stupid and not standard-compliant. Which is why I have a hard time imagining which browser this could be. Maybe MSIE 6.0.

Comment: Thanks for idea, looks realistic. I will try to record useragent at my log

Answer (score 1):

It is a CSS cursor which indicates that an element/object in a webpage is being resized. It is  part of Mozilla extensions for CSS (they begin with -moz). For more information read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-zoom-in).